# Building phalcon on Xubuntu for PHP 5.5.3 for API=20121212

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, phalcon

First, the *phalcon* installation on windows is a joke, copy+paste and its done. Awesome!

Now I am trying to install *phalcon* on my linux distro. I did everything as descriped here [Install Instructions](http://phalconphp.com/en/download), but I get the following error in the 'php_error_log' if I restart my apache:

```
[03-Oct-2013 00:01:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

As far as I know this means that I compiled the *phalcon.so* against a wrong PHP version. My guess now is that i need the php5-dev package equivalent for PHP version 5.5.3 but correct me if I'm wrong.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to compile phalcon on Linux to use it with PHP 5.5.3?
2. Where is my mistake and what can I do to fix it/compile against the right PHP Version? And if so, where do I get the PHP 5.5.3 dev package?

My system:

- phalcon 1.2.3
- Xubuntu 13.04
- Xampp 1.8.3-1 with PHP 5.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected for PHP 5.5.3 I need the php5-dev package for version 5.5.3.

But currently with apt-get (and no further software-package source editing) the newest version on Xubuntu 13.04 I can get is php5-dev for version 5.4.9. Therefore I had to downgrade Xampp to version 1.8.2-2 and now everything works.